# Register several composite scripts per ASP.NET Page

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager

I want to place several composite scripts to Page. But ScriptManager contains non-Enumerable property CompositeScript.

Is it possible to register several CompositeScript`s per Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can set it up that way; just out of curiosity, why is not one large script file OK?  You will get some performance benefits out of that as reducing script files increases performance...

Comment: Thanks for reply.
For example if i have got two pages and two colection of scripts A and B. First page includes both collections and second page includes only collection B. A and B are collections by reason of agile supporting.

Comment: In that scenario, you can add the scripts as part of collection B to the global level of the ScriptManager (say in the master page), and use the ScriptManagerProxy in the first page to include in the markup the scripts that are a part of collection A.  Or, you can programmably add scripts to manage the differentiations if you need to go to that level.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I added CompositScript in ScriptManagerProxy and got 2 composite scripts(registered on MasterPage and on required Page).
< asp:ScriptManagerProxy runat="server" >
    < CompositeScript >
        < Scripts >
            < asp:ScriptReference Path="~/JS/JScript3.js" / >
            < asp:ScriptReference Path="~/JS/JScript4.js" / >
        < / Scripts >
    < / CompositeScript >
< / asp:ScriptManagerProxy >